# Need to preprocess iis logs with python

Tags: python, regex

I am having the 12 gb iis log file with header as given below

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-01-05 00:00:00
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2014-01-05 00:00:00 192.168.1.208 GET /air/onlineMIS/AutoUpdateGV.aspx - 80 - 117.194.39.88 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+5.1;+rv:26.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/26.0 200 0 0 75
2014-01-05 00:00:00 192.168.1.208 GET /air/onlineMIS/AutoUpdateGV.aspx - 80 - 59.180.241.153 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 200 0
```

I want to remove

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-01-05 00:00:00
#Fields:
```

without creating a new file

I end with the script given below. thanks to  alecxe.

```
        line = file.readline()
        if not line.startswith('#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services '):
            file.seek(0)
            return
        # Skip the next 2 lines.
        for i in xrange(2):
            file.readline()
        # Parse the 4th line (regex)
        full_regex = []
        line = file.readline()
        fields = {
            'date': '(?P<date>^\d+[-\d+]+',
            'time': '[\d+:]+)',
            'cs-uri-stem': '(?P<path>/\S*)',
            'cs-uri-query': '(?P<query_string>\S*)',
            'c-ip': '(?P<ip>[\d*.]*)',
            'cs(User-Agent)': '(?P<user_agent>\S+)',
            'cs(Referer)': '(?P<referrer>\S+)',
            'sc-status': '(?P<status>\d+)',
            'sc-bytes': '(?P<length>\S+)',
            'cs-host': '(?P<host>\S+)',
        }
        # Skip the 'Fields: ' prefix.
        line = line[9:]
        for field in line.split():
            try:
                regex = fields[field]
            except KeyError:
                regex = '\S+'
            full_regex.append(regex)
        self.regex = re.compile(' '.join(full_regex))

        start_pos = file.tell()
        nextline = file.readline()
        file.seek(start_pos)
```

Comment: Don't torture python.  Use `grep`:  `grep -v '^#' filename`

Comment: Without a temp file: `sed -i '/^#/d' filename`

Comment: Yeah, why not sed or awk

Comment: I am running in a windows machine. So i can't use sed or awk.

Comment: After applying alecxe and various browsing i end up with the given script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module to modify the file in place, everything that is printed in the loop goes back to the file:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("input.txt", inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('#Fields '):
        print line[9:].strip()
    elif not line.startswith('#'):
        print line.strip()
```

As you can see, no need for regular expressions here, just check if the line starts with `#Fields` or `#`.

Comment: But it will skip the whole "#Fields: " line. I need to skip only "#Fields: "

Comment: @Francis not a problem, the concept remains the same. Just added one more `if` statement, see the updated answer.

Comment: This is still not correct, though hopefully most will spot the error. There is a missing colon after #Fields. It should show: 

if line.startswith('#Fields: '):